# Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2, Mongoid 2.3.3 - the poltergeist is in my datetimez

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I just spent a considerable amount of time trying to get this issue fixed, and although I did fix it (sort of) I'm nowhere near understanding what's going on.

Take a Mongoid model:

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :start, type: DateTime
  index :start

  def process(attrs = nil, role = :default, guard_protected_attributes = true)
    if attrs.keys.include?('start(1i)')
      now = DateTime.now
      year  = attrs.delete('start(1i)').to_i || now.year
      month = attrs.delete('start(2i)').to_i || now.month
      day   = attrs.delete('start(3i)').to_i || now.day
      hour  = attrs.delete('start(4i)').to_i || now.hour
      min   = attrs.delete('start(5i)').to_i || now.minute
      sec   = attrs.delete('start(6i)').to_i || 0 # seconds
      zone  = attrs.delete('start(7i)').to_i || 0 # UTC

      # I'm not sure what is happening here, but we need to adjust the hour
      # otherwise Rails/Mongoid will mangle the time...
      start = DateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, zone)
      # First we set the time and self.start will be wrong by 6 hours (my timezone)
      self.start = start
      # We do this and the time will change by several hours!!!
      self.start -= 0.seconds
      # Can't make a simple substraction as we'll get a Rational? The WTFs just keep piling up...
      diff = (self.start.to_i - start.to_i).seconds
      self.start -= diff
      self.start -= diff # Yeah, twice?
    end

    super(attrs, role, guard_protected_attributes)
  end
end
```

Why the `process` method? Well, I can't let the `start` attribute be handled by `Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes`, as "something" will "fix" it by adjusting it using my local time zone (haven't figured out which brilliant code is doing this).

In that code, the `start` variable will always have the correct time, but as you saw, self.start has to be beaten with a mallet until the time is correct too.

Weird? Man don't get me started. This is related to Rails multi-parameter attributes, which allows me to use several `select` tags for setting a date/time (the `start(1i)` stuff).

`Time.zone` is UTC, so I don't know why it's using my local time zone to mangle the time.

But the weirdest stuff is why do I have to make so many adjustments...

I'm not expecting to find a real solution anytime soon, but I wanted to know your thoughts.

PS: Awww, SO didn't let me add the `poltergeist` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to:

```
Mongoid::Config.use_utc = true
Mongoid::Config.use_activesupport_time_zone = true
```

That still doesn't explain the weird behavior do. Or maybe it does and I'm not seeing it :)

Comment: use_utc should = false
as per https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1475 && https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/878

Comment: also the field should be a "Time" object not a "DateTime" for it to work properly